# AWS API Gateway - 400: Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an HTTP proxy endpoint, that when tested works properly:

```
Request: /results?auth=abc123&id=9876&start=2016-08-20&end=2016-09-01
Status: 200
Latency: 265 ms
```

When targeted via Postman returns the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bad Request</h1>
        <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
            <br />
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The endpoint is setup as follows (some info redacted):

[image: api-gateway-screenshot]

There is no authentication or authorization setup (it's a direct pass through query parameter).

Answer (score 4):

I spent hours on this.

In my case, this was only happening from a XHR, causing a CORS error during preflight

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

even though the headers were properly configured being returned from the backend (via HTTP Proxy integration) and [CORS was properly configured in AWS API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html).

I tracked down the problem to the unencoded curly brackets used in the XHR query parameter:

```
where=[{"field": "client_id", "op": "eq", "value": 1}]
```

URL encoding those characters fixed the 400 Bad Request. Phew!

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I think you've just saved hours of my life.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the "HTTP Proxy" setting was causing this. Instead of doing this, I manually mapped each request query parameter in the integration step. By unchecking HTTP Proxy and doing this manual mapping, every request is properly proxied without issue.

[image: http_proxy_disabled_image]